# How can I get configurable product from a sales order?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, sales-order

I've created a button in the back end of my Magento 1.9 website called "Send to Printers" that I need to send JSON data to my printers API. I'm able to get some of the order information using the following:

```
$orderID = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_id');
$order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($orderID);
$customer = $order->getShippingAddress()->getData();
```

Unfortunately though the following code isn't allowing me to get information about the items of that order:

```
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
foreach ($orderItems as $itemId => $item) {
  if ($item->getParentItem()) {
    // This is a simple product assigned to a configurable
    // You can get every single details by loading it
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $product->load($item->getSku(),'sku');
    // This variable will store all the data
    $data = $product->getData();
} else if ($item->getHasChildren()) {
    // This is a configurable product
}
}
```

The foreach never reaches any of the `if` statements. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Magento is  **insert multiple rows at sales_flat_order_item** whenever a **configurable product will order**.

The **sku** field are `always be simple product sku`.But  in those multiple rows,**one of rows**, **product_id** field value is **configurable product id**  and that row is identified by `parent_item_id =null`.

So, if you use **getAllVisibleItems**  instead of `getAllItems` then it will better and product_type field for getting Product type of order item.

No need of use below code for getting product type.

```
if ($item->getParentItem()) {
   ....
} else if ($item->getHasChildren()) {
   ....
}
```

**Try below code:**

```
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
foreach ($orderItems as $itemId => $item) {
    $item->getSku();
        $item->getProductId();
    $item->getProductType(); // use this for getting product type
}
```

Comment: This does get me the product ID and type,  but it gets the ID for the configurable product when actually I need its child ordered simple product ID etc.

Comment: For getting simple product sku try code `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($item->getSku());`

Answer (score 1):

Hi check below code may be help you

```
$OrderNumber = "100000201";//Put your order Number here

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($OrderNumber, 'increment_id');

$order->getAllVisibleItems();


$orderItems = $order->getItemsCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('product_type', array('eq'=>'simple'))
    ->load();

foreach($orderItems as $sItem) {

    //Ignore conf for now
    //Alt. Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE = 'simple';
    if($sItem->getProductType() == "simple")
    {



        echo "\n*********************************\nMage Order #: ".$OrderNumber."<br/>";
        //Simple Item Info from Order
        echo "Type: ".$sItem->getProductType()."<br/>";
        echo "Order Id: ".$sItem->getOrderId()."<br/>";
        echo "Product Id: ".$sItem->getProductId()."<br/>";
        echo "Item Id: ".$sItem->getId()."<br/>";
        echo "Item Name: ".$sItem->getName()."<br/>";
        echo "Item Sku: ".$sItem->getSku()."<br/>";
        echo "Item Price: ".$sItem->getPrice()."<br/>";

        $pItemId = $sItem->getParentItemId();
        echo "Parent Item Id: ".$pItemId."<br/>";

        echo "<br/>*****<br/>";
        //Get Parent Item Information
        $item = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->load("$pItemId"); //use an item_id here

        //Testing, want to see whats inside the parent/configurable item?
        //print_r($item->toArray());

        echo "Parent Type: ".$item->getProductType()."<br/>";
        echo "Parent Order Id: ".$item->getOrderId()."<br/>";
        echo "Product Id: ".$item->getProductId()."<br/>";
        echo "Item Id: ".$item->getId()."<br/>";
        echo "Parent Item Price: ".$item->getPrice()."<br/>";
        echo "Qty: ".$qty = intval($item->getQtyOrdered())."<br/>";

        //get Active Product Data
        $nProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($sItem->getProductId());
        $nSku = $nProduct->getSku();
        echo "new Product UPC:".$nUpc = $nProduct->getUpc() . "<br/>";
        echo "new Product Price:".$nPrice = $nProduct->getPrice(). "<br/>";

        }
    }
```